# Selecting multiple rows of values (a,b,c) under a column x

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of 1617 obs and 202 variables which includes a variable `State`. there are 52 independent states. I want to randomly select 5 states, but all entries under those 5 states or sample all entries under 5 specific states.

I have tried using this:

```
A <- subset(Iped, STABBR == c("PA", "DC", "MD", "DE", "VA"))
```

but it does not return all entries with the above values. It only selects 45 entries out of about 230.

I want to be able to subset to include 5 states and count entries under each state.

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(head(lped))` in your question? That way we can help you with this

Comment: `A <- subset(Iped, STABBR %in%c("PA", "DC", "MD", "DE", "VA")) `

Comment: Thanks this worked. How about to do a random sample of 5 states without specifying and getting all entries.

Answer (score 0):

To get 5 random states, do `sample(unique(Iped$State), 5)` if `Iped` is the name of your dataframe.

Your final subset would be `A <- subset(Iped, STABBR %in% sample(unique(Iped$State), 5))`

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question completely, and without a reproducible example it gets even more difficult. But here's a `data.table` solution I think you can use:

```
# load library
require(data.table)

# define data:
set.seed(1)
states <- data.table(a = 1:1000, State = sample(LETTERS, 1000, TRUE))

# filter those states in a random sample of 5 (obviously not replacing them!): that's what gets before the first comma. Then count them (that's the .N) by the name of each State (that's the by):
states[State %in% sample(unique(State), 5, FALSE), .N, by = State]
```